AttributeError: 'ArcGISProject' object has no attribute 'listStyleItems'; ArcGIS Pro 3.1.4; Python Notebook
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject( path_in + name_in)
aprx.listStyleItems()

returns:
AttributeError: 'ArcGISProject' object has no attribute 'listStyleItems'

While all other functions work (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/arcgisproject-class.htm). Even if objects are empty, they return: [] 
I work with ArcGIS Pro 3.1.4; Python Notebook.

I would assume the listStyleItems method was added to ArcGIS Pro 3.2 and does not exist in 3.1.
If you use the drop down at the top of the page you reference (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/arcgisproject-class.htm), you can select 3.1, 3.2 and 3.3. The function is documented in 3.2 and 3.3, but not in 3.1
